# Lookbehind starting at the end of a string

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I am sure this must have been asked before, but for some reason finding answers in the archive to problems with regular expressions is particularly difficult for me.

I would like to do a lookbehind starting at the end of a string.

Example string:

```
"This is a string with lots of white space_and-other.stuff"
```

I only want the part of the string that has the very last whitespace in front of it.
So far I have the following:

```
(?<=\s).+$
```

which gives me everything after the first whitespace, even though I am matching against the end of the string. I the root of my problems must have something to do with lookbehinds having to be a predefined number of characters, but I don't know how to do it without a lookbehind.

Comment: Searching for a regex still does report the *first* occurrence. So your lookbehind expression matches right after the first whitespace. From there, it matches at least one character up to the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need lookbehind. You can get it using this regex:

```
\S+$
```